# WP_insert_post is also adding a menu item

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've got the following code that executes on activation of my wordpress plugin.

It does create the page, but it also adds a nav menu item which I do not want to have.

Can someone help me as I can't see where I have gone wrong.

I know it adds a nav menu item as well because looking at the database in the table wp_posts, the post_date is exactly the same for the post_type Page and nav_menu_item.

```
public static function activate() {
    global $myplugin;
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'install-sql.php';

    //Add a front end page
    $author_id = 9;
    $slug = 'myplugin';
    $title = "My Plugin";
    $content = '[myplugin_render]';
    $page = array(
        'post_author'           => 1,
        'post_content'          => $content,
        'post_title'            => $title,
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'post_type'             => 'page',
        'comment_status'        => 'closed',
        'ping_status'           => 'closed',
        'guid'                  => '',
        'import_id'             => 0,
        'context'               => ''
    );
    if( null == get_page_by_title( $title ) ) {
        wp_insert_post( $page );
    } else {
        $page = get_page_by_title( $title );
        if ( is_page($page->ID) ) {
            $post = array(
                'ID'            => $page->ID,
                'post_content'  => $content
                );
            wp_update_post( $post );
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wild guess: Go to appearance => menus, choose your menu, under Settings, is the checkbox next to "Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu" checked?

If it is: uncheck it :)

Comment: You my friend, are a genius! Thank you very much, it was driving me insane!

Answer (score 1):

For those who come here looking to programattically side-step the setting `Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu` - my solution is to add the page as normal, then call the following function afterward.

```
Example:

$pageID = wp_insert_post($args);
zeroBSCRM_wp_removePageFromMenus($pageID);
```

Here's my function for removing a page from all front-end menus (using page ID) :

```
/**
 * Removes a page from front-end menus by ID
 *
 * @param int id        WordPress Page ID
 *
 * @return int count of removed
 */
function zeroBSCRM_wp_removePageFromMenus($pageID=-1){

    // only if a valid $pageID
    if ($pageID > 0){

        // get menu locations
        $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

        // cycle through (any) and get menu in slot
        if (is_array($locations)) foreach ($locations as $location => $menuID){

            // Retrieve Menu & Pages in menu
            $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($menuID);            
            $pagesItem = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu, array("object"=>"page"));

            // Cycle through pages & remove target menu page link if present
            if (is_array($pagesItem)) 
              foreach ($pagesItem as $page)
                if ($page->object_id == $pageID) wp_delete_post($page->db_id);

        }

    }

    return 0;

}
```